# CVXPY DCPError in custom optimization problem

Tags: python, cvxpy

I'm tried to implementation of the "Maximum product SINR -based power allocation" method.

first of all, I changed to the maxprod_sinr Matlab function converted to the python language.

But the converted code is not working, also occurred the error as below:
[image]

I Implemented the 'maxprod_SINR' function as follow

```
# Variable for the K x L BS power allocation matrix
rho_p = cp.Variable((self.K, self.N))

# Variable for the K x L SINR matrix
sinr = cp.Variable((self.K, self.N))

# Create constraints.
constraints = []

# Form objective
obj = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(sinr))

for j in range(self.N):
  for k in range(self.K):
    # SINR constraints of UE k in cell j
    if signal[k,j] > 0:
      # sinr[k,j]*(cp.sum(cp.sum(rho_p.T @ interference[:,:,k,j])) + 1) <= (rho_p[k,j]*signal[k,j]);
      constraints.append(sinr[k,j]*(cp.sum(cp.sum(rho_p.T @ interf[:,:,k,j])) + 1) <= (rho_p[k,j]*signal[k,j]))
      constraints.append(rho_p[k,j] >= 0)

    # This applies if UE k in cell J is inactive
    else:
      constraints.append(sinr[k,j] == 1)
      constraints.append(rho_p[k,j] >= 0)

  constraints.append(cp.sum(rho_p[:,j]) <= self.Pmax)

# Maximzing the power indirectly by prod(sinr) the power constraints
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
prob.solve()

# The problem was not solved by CVX, for some reason, and we then consider equal power allocation
if prob.status == 'infeasible':
  feasible = False
  rhoSolution = (self.Pmax / self.K) * np.ones((self.K, self.N))

# The problem was solved by CVX
else:
  feasible = True
  rhoSolution = rho_p

# Converting variable() to ndarray()
rhoSolution = np.array(rhoSolution.value)
rhoSolution = rhoSolution.copy()

return feasible, rhoSolution
```

Comment: Your main constraint can roughly be reduced to the form ``x*y<=z`` (where ``x`` is ``sinr``, ``y`` is some linear combination of ``rho_p`` and ``z`` is some multiple of ``rho_p``). The inequality ``x*y<= z`` defines a non-convex constraint hence cvxpy will not accept it.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you for your kind response. Then How can I expression of my constraints... Unfortunately, I'm not friendly to the CVXPY.

Comment: I think you need to be working in GP mode https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/dgp/power_control.html but this is just a guess. I'm not a sinr expert.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you for your response. I'll try to implement a convex function with you suggest idea :>

Comment: ``gp=True`` when calling solve might be what you need at some point.